# ¿Cómo obtener una suma en una columna para un día semanal de la semana actual en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una columna en TIMESTAMP y una columna con un valor numerico de tipo:

```
|---------------------|---------------------|
|        fecha        |        valor        |
|---------------------|---------------------|
| 2017-03-31 08:34:50 |          5          |
| 2017-03-27 08:34:50 |          4          |
| 2017-03-18 08:34:50 |          2          |
| 2017-03-27 08:34:50 |          8          |
|---------------------|---------------------|
```

Necesito sumar `SUM(valor)` cuando la fecha es un dia de la semanade esta semana.

Por **ejemplo**, actualmente estamos a viernes 31, entonces la semana empieza en Lunes 27. Tengo que sumar todos los valores que están en el último, por ejemplo Lunes, día 27. Quiero obtener el `(4+8)` = 10. Y así para todas los días de la semana posteriormente.Necesito algo como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM(valor) WHERE fecha = "el Lunes pasado";
```

Necesito que esa query automáticamente reconozca cuando empieza la semana y sumar los valores para un día de la semana seleccionado (en el ejemplo era Lunes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`weekday`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) que te devuelve un índice numérico que representa en cual día de la semana estás con respecto al comienzo de la semana.  En el caso de un día viernes (como `2017-03-31`), el resultado es `4`.

Entonces puedes usar ese resultado y restar esa cantidad de días al día actual para encontrar el lunes anterior:

```
select curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/FKCB27028)</kbd>

De modo que combinándolo con tu consulta, vendría siendo:

```
select sum(valor)
  from tbl
 where date(fecha) = (curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day)
```

O, si quieres evitar usar la función `date()` con la columna `fecha` en caso has definido un índice en esa columna y deseas usarla para mejor rendimiento, puedes escribir la consulta de forma un poco más complicada de esta forma:

```
select sum(valor)
  from tbl
 where fecha >= (curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day)
   and fecha < (curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) - 1 day)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Me podrías decir cómo con `select curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day` se obtiene el lunes 27 y cómo podría obtener el martes, miercoles, etc. ?

Comment: Super, muchas gracias !! Ahora entiendo

Comment: Martes: `(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) - 1 day)`, Miércoles: `(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) - 2 day)`, Jueves: `(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) - 3 day)`, etc... le sigues agregando uno para ir consiguiendo un día diferente.

Comment: Incredible, has salvado una la vida!